# Why are if expressions frowned upon in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

This has been a question I've been wondering for a while. if statements are staples in most programming languages (at least then ones I've worked with), but in Haskell it seems like it is quite frowned upon. I understand that for complex situations, Haskell's pattern matching is much cleaner than a bunch of ifs, but is there any real difference?

For a simple example, take a homemade version of sum (yes, I know it could just be `foldr (+) 0`):

```
sum :: [Int] -> Int
-- separate all the cases out
sum [] = 0
sum (x:xs) = x + sum xs

-- guards
sum xs
    | null xs = 0
    | otherwise = (head xs) + sum (tail xs)

-- case
sum xs = case xs of
    [] -> 0
    _ -> (head xs) + sum (tail xs)

-- if statement
sum xs = if null xs then 0 else (head xs) + sum (tail xs)
```

As a second question, which one of these options is considered "best practice" and why? My professor way back when always used the first method whenever possible, and I'm wondering if that's just his personal preference or if there was something behind it.

Comment: Haskell has if *expressions*, not *statements*.

Comment: Quick question, can the case version be written as
`sum xs = case xs of
    [] -> 0
    x:xs -> xs) + sum xs`
?

Comment: @ShannonSeverance, yes: `sum xs = case xs of { [] -> 0; (x:xs') -> x + sum xs' }`.

Comment: Different language, SML, but IIRC, my professor liked patterns inside case expressions instead of multiple function definitions for the different cases.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The problem with your examples is not the `if` expressions, it's the use of partial functions like `head` and `tail`. If you try to call either of these with an empty list, it throws an exception.

```
> head []
*** Exception: Prelude.head: empty list
> tail []
*** Exception: Prelude.tail: empty list
```

If you make a mistake when writing code using these functions, the error will not be detected until run time. If you make a mistake with pattern matching, your program will not compile.

For example, let's say you accidentally switched the `then` and `else` parts of your function.

```
-- Compiles, throws error at run time.
sum xs = if null xs then (head xs) + sum (tail xs) else 0

-- Doesn't compile. Also stands out more visually.
sum [] = x + sum xs
sum (x:xs) = 0
```

Note that your example with guards has the same problem.

Comment: That makes sense. But is there any real difference if it's written correctly? I know head, null, and tail are all very fast list operations, so is there any advantage to using the pure pattern matching version?

Comment: @swanysims: `head`, `null` and `tail` are all implemented using pattern mathcing, and they are prime candidates for inlining. GHC's optimizer will turn both into the exact same code, so focus on what makes the code easier to read, understand and work with.

Answer (score 20):

I think the [Boolean Blindness](http://existentialtype.wordpress.com/2011/03/15/boolean-blindness/) article answers this question very well.  The problem is that boolean values have lost all their semantic meaning as soon as you construct them.  That makes them a great source for bugs and also makes the code more difficult to understand.

Comment: I would elaborate on this just a bit. The phrase "lost all their semantic meaning" means that in order to understand `True`, you also have to understand what `True` means. If `authorizeUser` and `nonAuthorizedUser` both return `True`, you clearly have to examine the function to tell the difference. Whereas you could have something like: `authorizeUser :: Either Forbidden User` and it would be much clearer.

Answer (score 16):

Your first version, the one preferred by your prof, has the following advantages compared to the others:

1. no mention of `null`
2. list components are named in the pattern, so no mention of `head` and `tail`.

I do think that this one is considered "best practice".

What's the big deal? Why would we want to avoid especially `head` and `tail`? Well, everybody knows that those functions are not total, so one automatically tries to make sure that all cases are covered. A pattern match on [] not only stands out more than `null xs`, a series of pattern matches can be checked by the compiler for completeness. Hence, the idiomatic version with complete pattern match is easier to grasp (for the trained Haskell reader) and to proof exhaustive by the compiler.

The second version is slightly better than the last one because one sees at once that all cases are handled. Still, in the general case the RHS of the second equation could be longer and there could be a where clauses with a couple of definitions, the last of them could be something like:

```
where
   ... many definitions here ...
   head xs = ... alternative redefnition of head ...
```

To be absolutly sure to understand what the RHS does, one has to make sure common names have not been redefined.

The 3rd version is the worst one IMHO: a) The 2nd match fails to deconstruct the list and still uses head and tail. b) The *case* is slightly more verbose than the equivalent notation with 2 equations.

Answer (score 8):

In many programming languages, if-statements are fundamental primitives, and things like switch-blocks are just syntax sugar to make deeply-nested if-statements easier to write.

Haskell does it the other way around. Pattern matching is the fundamental primitive, and an if-expression is literally just syntax sugar for pattern matching. Similarly, constructs like `null` and `head` are simply user-defined functions, which are all ultimately implemented using pattern matching. So pattern matching is the thing at the bottom of it all. (And therefore potentially more efficient than calling user-defined functions.)

In many cases - such as the ones you list above - it's simply a matter of style. The compiler can almost certainly optimise things to the point where all versions are roughly equal in performance. But *generally* [not always!] pattern matching makes it clearer exactly what you're trying to achieve.

(It's annoyingly easy to write an if-expression where you get the two alternatives the wrong way around. You'd *think* it would be a rare mistake, but it's surprisingly common. With a pattern match, there's little chance of making that specific mistake, although there's still plenty of other things to screw up.)

Answer (score 6):

Each call to `null`, `head` and `tail` entails a pattern match. But the 1st version in your answer does just one pattern match, and reuses its results through named components of the pattern.

Just for that, it is better. But it is also more visually apparent, more readable.

Answer (score 5):

Pattern matching is better than a string of if-then-else statements for (at least) the following reasons:

1. it is more declarative
2. it interacts well with sum-types

Pattern matching helps to reduce the amount of "accidental complexity" in your code - that is, code that is really more about implementation details rather than the essential logic of your program.

In most other languages when the compier/run-time sees a string of if-then-else statements it has no choice but to test the conditions in exactly the order the programmer specified them. But pattern matching encourages the programmer to focus more on describing what should happen versus how things should be performed. Due to purity and immutability of values in Haskell the compiler can consider the collection of patterns as a whole and decide the how best to implement them.

An analogy would be C's `switch` statement. If you dump the assembly code for various switch statements you will see that sometimes the compiler will generate a chain/tree of comparisons and in other cases it will generate a jump table. The programmer uses the same syntax in both cases - the compiler chooses the implementation based on what the comparison values are. If they form a contiguous block of values the jump table method is used, otherwise a comparison tree is used. And this separation of concerns allows the compiler to implement even more strategies in the future if other patterns among the comparison values are detected.