# Converting a list to a list of lists

Tags: list, haskell

I have a list of tuples, the first element of the tuples can be 'a','b','c' . I want to create a list of 3 lists from that tuple list. First list has to have 'a' tuples, second 'b' tuples and third 'c' tuples. Here is the code :

```
group mylist = group2 mylist [[],[],[]]

group2 mylist xs = if mylist == [] then xs
            else if getFirst (head mylist) == 'a' then group2 (tail mylist) ([head mylist]++[head xs])++ (tail xs) 
            else if getFirst (head mylist) == 'b' then group2 (tail mylist) [head xs] ++ ((head mylist):[head (tail xs)]) ++ (tail xs) 
            else if getFirst (head mylist) == 'c' then group2 (tail mylist) (init xs) ++ ((head mylist):[last xs])
            else xs
```

I get this error :

> ```
> Couldn't match expected type `(Char, t0, t1)'
>             with actual type `[a0]'
> In the expression: []
> In the second argument of `group2', namely `[[], [], []]'
> In the expression: group2 mylist [[], [], []] Failed, modules loaded: none.
> ```

Sample Input :

```
[(c,1,2),(a,2,4),(c,5,6),(b,7,8),(a,9,1),(b,3,5),(c,2,5),(a,6,2),(c,1,8),(b,7,3),(a,4,4)]
```

Output :

```
[[(a,2,4),(a,9,1),(a,6,2),(a,4,4)],[(b,7,8),(b,3,5),(b,7,3)],[(c,1,2),(c,5,6),(c,2,5),(c,1,8)]]
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Would you mind to give some sample input and output to make your question clearer?

Comment: @LeeDuhem I put an input and output. Thanks.

Comment: You might want to read [this post about style advice regarding `if` statements etc.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16572446/why-are-if-expressions-frowned-upon-in-haskell). In a nutshell: using `head` is almost always a bad idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll find this easier if you use pattern matching:

```
group :: [(Char, a, b)] -> [[(Char, a, b)]]
group = group' [[],[],[]]

group' :: [[(Char, a, b)]] -> [(Char, a, b)] -> [[(Char, a, b)]]
group' l [] = l
group' [as, bs, cs] (t@('a', _, _):ts) = group' [t:as, bs, cs] ts
group' [as, bs, cs] (t@('b', _, _):ts) = group' [as, t:bs, cs] ts
group' [as, bs, cs] (t@('c', _, _):ts) = group' [as, bs, t:cs] ts
group' l (_:ts) = group' l ts
```

Comment: Adding a `map reverse` should make this solution order-preserving as well.